# iOS app failed to install - How to get details about the error?

Tags: ios, air, itunes

I built an iPhone app with Adobe Air and tried to install it through iTunes Sync. 
I'm getting this error message after syncing:

```
"com.test.name" failed to install
```

How can I get a detailed error message to figure out what went wrong?

My setup:

```
Windows
iTunes 11.1.5.5
iPhone 3Gs 
iOS 6.1
Adobe Air 3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Adobe AIR cannot publish for iPhone devices below the iPhone 4.  See this document for details about what hardware you can target:

http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html

Comment: That's not correct, I got it working after creating a new certificate.